# Is there a way to reduce or prevent crashing when trading?

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas

I've always had trouble when buying caravan cards. It seems that if I try to buy too many, when I "accept" the transaction, the game will pause, and then crash. I've had some success at getting around this by just buying a few cards at a time, "banking" the transaction, and continuing shopping.

On my current playthrough, this crashing is happening at most vendors, and with items other than caravan cards. I've just crashed 6 times in a row at Gun Runners trying to get all the stuff I want, and sell off all the stuff I've collected. I kept trying smaller and smaller lots. Toward the end, I was just buying a couple things at a time, and it still wasn't helping. The last time it crashed, it seems to have corrupted my quick save file, and don't feel like starting over with a dozen trades again. (In fact, at this point, I just don't even feel like playing any more.)

Is there any way to fix this, or at least tip the odds back in favor of NOT crashing?

Comment: I've never encountered this on the PC... What platform are you on? If you're on a PC, what are your specs?

Comment: Wow. I never imagined that this would be rare. Yeah, I'm on a PC. I've got a dual-core 3 GHz, 8 GB RAM, striped 10K RPM Raptor hard drives, dual 8800 GT's, and I use the built-in sound card. I run at 1152x768 with low-ish AA and filtering.

Comment: I'm really sorry, google-ing revealed other people with the same problem, but no fix. 
Unrelated, you seem to have a good PC, why do you play with low(ish) quality? I'm on a HD4850 with 4 GB RAM and can play it with absolute full details at 1080p. I can understand the resolution if your monitor doesn't support it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response over at [/r/fnv](http://www.reddit.com/r/fnv/comments/ig3r5/how_can_i_keep_from_crashing_at_vendors/c23j11l) that seems to have helped. As I said there: "I tried [verifying the game files], and there was one file that didn't verify and had to be re-downloaded. The jury's out on whether this fixed the problem, since it's proof by exhaustion, but I did run 3 other vendors besides Gun Runners: the guy at McCarran, Gun Runners at the interstate intersection, and the guy at the Crimson Caravan, and had no crashes."

Comment: Indeed, I've continued to play, and have had no further problems.

Answer (score -1):

It would seem that the game is particularly full of bugs, so the first advice will be to always keep your game fully updated.

After that is said there are [lots of bugs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Gun_Runners_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)) related to the Gun Runners area. And there are [even more bugs](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_bugs) in other parts of the game.

I also found a [specific advice](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959557-/57044468) about the Vendortron, where the fix is to wait 3 days so his stock/caps reset to normal levels and then don't surpass 32,000 caps again.

[Here be dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons) best sums up this game :)